# Subtraction in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object that has an integer type of attribute. I want to subtract 1 from the attribute after a particular action. I tried in the controller:

```
  def subtraction
    #find a item  and get the value, let's say value is 40
    item = Item.where(id: params[:id]).pluck(:value)

    # subtract 1 from the value and i thought it would be 40-1
    after_subtraction = item.to_i - 1

    #update the value
    final = item.update(value: after_subtraction)
  end
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_i' for [40]:Array
```

When I remove `to_i`, it says `-` is not a method. Is there any way to update the stored value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to handle is

```
item = Item.find_by(id: params[:id]).value
```

**pluck** will return you array, which is not necessary in your case here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way you constructed the query, it gets the value for all entries that match the `where` condition, hence what is returned by the `.pluck` method is an array on which you cannot call `.to_i` method.

I guess what you want to do is to pluck the value you need from the first entry that matches your query, hence you can refactor as below

```
def subtraction
  #find the first item with id supplied
  item = Item.where(id: params[:id]).first

  #after subtraction value
  val = item.value - 1

  #update the value
  final = item.update(value: val)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As `pluck` returns an array you can not use `to_i` for conversion here.

Seeing your code, you can refactor it like this,

```
  def subtraction
    # Find the item first
    item = Item.find(params[:id])

    # Subtract 1 from the value column of the item
    item.value -= 1

    # Save the modification of the item
    item.save!
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly convert array in to to_i . please use below method

```
after_subtraction = item.join.to_i - 1
```

Yes, Nithin's answer is more valid. you can go with nithin's answer. you don't need to use **pluck** until you want array of multiple values.